# Cross compiling pdcurses from arch linux to windows

Tags: c, console-application, cross-compiling, pdcurses

I'm trying to cross-compile a simple "Hello World!" program, from arch linux to windows

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();

    printw("Hello World!");
    refresh();
    getch();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

And then I compile using mingw:

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc hello.c -o hello-x64.exe -lpdcurses.dll`

And when I run the program, it crashes. Here's it's [trace](http://pastebin.com/rGVeBYvu)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're including the curses.h from the PDCurses package, and not the system curses.h (which is ncurses).

Also, although it's probably not relevant to the problem, stdio.h is not needed here.